# crystal report summary

Tags: crystal-reports, summary

Data Table

```
pack_ID  qty
   1      3
   1      4
   1      9
   2      10
   3      1
   3      3
```

I want to display the following in Crystal Report

```
pack_ID   qty
   1       16
   2       10
   3        4
```

How ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert group on pack_id, insert field summary (sum(qty)) into group footer, hide details section.

Answer (score 0):

simple to do in the sql:

```
SELECT pack_ID,SUM(qty) FROM Table GROUP BY pack_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one another way to implement this solution is that if you have less pack_id and need to show this details into particular section instead of dynamically to show the sum of each and every records. Below are the steps:

1. Create formula **Qty_Count_Pack_1** which will store the number of quantity with pack_id 1. You need to create number of formula as per number of pack_id.

   ```
     if ({command.Pack_Id}) = 1) THEN
       {command.Qty}
     else
       0
   ```
2. Use Summary formula field to sum the Qty which will give the summary of qty for pack_Id 1.

   ```
   Sum({@Qty_Count_Pack_1},{command.pack_ID})
   ```

Answer (score -1):

There are 2  steps as:

1. Insert Group of pack_ID
2. Copy qty from detail block to Group of pack_ID the same line 
   so u can see result as u expect.
   [image]